# Something unknown added this to my htaccess. What to make of it?

Tags: .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

Today I noticed that the `.htaccess` file in my `public_html` root was modified a couple of months ago.

Before every `RewriteRule` line, some bot or somebody has added the following three lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
# lines above were inserted above each rewrite such as the following
RewriteRule ^home/? /index.html     [QSA,END,NC]
```

I also noticed that I had a `public_html/.well-known/acme-challenge/` empty directory.  I have two questions.

1. What should I make of this?
2. What effect do the rewrite conditions have? My rewrites still seem to work as before.

#### Update

It seems to have to do with [Let's Encrypt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Let%E2%80%99s_Encrypt) TLS cert auto-renewal, so the folder was probably created by the certification bot. But why do such a hatch job of my `.htaccess`? the trio of lines I pointed out appears, as I said, before *every* rewrite. So it adds a lot of bloat and confusion to the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what cPanel does automatically in the `.htaccess` file to protect its setup. It just stops your rules from affecting `.cpaneldcv` files, some cPanel text files named with 32 characters `.txt` and the `acme-challenge` files.

`acme-challenge` is indeed likely to do with TLS certificate generation.

Comment: Thanks. I manage my `.htaccess` locally and update it via `Git`, so it's annoying to have it polluted so. Could I just add one rule that will say "*if request uri is one of the 3, don't rewrite*" and stick it near the top? That should work right since `.htaccess` files are parsed top to bottom.

Comment: [This thread on the cPanel forum](https://features.cpanel.net/topic/ability-to-prevent-autossl-editing-htaccess-fles) is discussing it, seems to be possible.

Comment: Yes. Within `WHM >> Server Configuration >> Tweak Settings` is an option to `Use global DCV excludes`. When enabled, it removes the need for cPanel to edit individual `.htaccess` files. Thank you.